# setup multiple cameras for capturing images

Tags: c#, aforge

I am trying to collect images from up to 6 different cameras.  The code I have works, but it does not seem very object oriented since I have to do a switch on the index of the cameras to set the NewFrame event handler to individually named handlers to put the image in the picturebox for each camera.  Is there a better way to do this (see code below).

```
    private void ImageCollector_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcams = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        Cameras = new VideoCaptureDevice[webcams.Count];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (FilterInfo CaptureDevice in webcams)
        {
            // Enable the cameras display
            ViewLabelflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
            ImageLabelflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
            ViewflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
            ImageflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
            CameracomboBox.Items.Add(CaptureDevice.Name);
            try
            {
                Cameras[index] = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcams[index].MonikerString);
                switch (index)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam1_NewFrame);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam2_NewFrame);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam3_NewFrame);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam4_NewFrame);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam5_NewFrame);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam6_NewFrame);
                        break;
                }//endswitch

                Cameras[index].Start();
            }//endtry
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }//endcatch
        }//endforeach
        CameracomboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        index++;
    }//endImageCollector_Load
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good for you, you can identify code smell!

I don't know how NewFrame works, but it probably has a sender which is the Camera that triggered the event, so you can do this.

```
    foreach (FilterInfo CaptureDevice in webcams)
    {
        // Enable the cameras display
        ViewLabelflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
        ImageLabelflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
        ViewflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
        ImageflowLayoutPanel.Controls[index].Visible = true;
        CameracomboBox.Items.Add(CaptureDevice.Name);
        try
        {
            Cameras[index] = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcams[index].MonikerString);
            Cameras[index].NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);


            Cameras[index].Start();
        }//endtry
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }//endcatch
    }//endforeach
    CameracomboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    index++;


 public void cam_NewFrame(object sender, EventArgs e){

     VideoCaptureDevice cam = sender as VideoCaptureDevice;
     //do what you need to do with cam here.

 }
```

This works assuming that the sender is set to the camera object.